# smtp/pop3 server and mx record

Tags: smtp, mx-record

I run smtp and pop3 server in local computer. I have domain name and set up MX record for this domain. Please, explain me anybody how smtp server name depend at MX record? And where must i specify the MX record in smtp server config?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe first paragraph of [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record)'s entry will help

> A mail exchanger record (MX record) is
>   a type of resource record in the
>   Domain Name System that specifies a
>   mail server responsible for accepting
>   email messages on behalf of a
>   recipient's domain and a preference
>   value used to prioritize mail delivery
>   if multiple mail servers are
>   available. The set of MX records of a
>   domain name specifies how email should
>   be routed with the Simple Mail
>   Transfer Protocol.

So, MX records specify which server is responsible for a domain.

On the side of the receiving server you don't need to specify a MX record, but only domain name and you have to allow connection from the internet.

Once that is done you have

- MX record which allows any mail server to know where to route mail (to which server)
- a receiving server which accepts the mail

Result is that mail is delivered.

Comment: The smtp server name must be same as mx record?

Comment: MX record *is* a mail server.